# Windows 8 questions (Why App.Current.Resources? Why Use GridView Items?)

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have 2 questions regarding [a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx) that I am going through.

Q1.

Through the tutorial they use a datasource

> Using the data in the app
>
> To use the data in the app, you create an instance of the data source
>   as a resource in App.xaml. You name the instance feedDataSource.
>
> BR211380.wedge(en-us,WIN.10).gifTo add a resource to an app
>
> ```
> Double-click App.xaml in Solution Explorer. The file opens in the XAML editor.
> Add the resource declaration, <local:FeedDataSource x:Key="feedDataSource"/>, to the root ResourceDictionary, after the
> MergedDictionaries collection.
> ```

and then they use it in the OnLaunch method.

```
 var connectionProfile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
 if (connectionProfile != null)
 {
     FeedDataSource feedDataSource = (FeedDataSource)App.Current.Resources["feedDataSource"];
     if (feedDataSource != null)
     {
         if (feedDataSource.Feeds.Count == 0)
         {
             await feedDataSource.GetFeedsAsync();
         }
     }
 }
```

I am wondering why do they store it in resource? Wy not just create an instance of the class and get the results from it?

Q2.

Later down the article they use this datasource items with "grid view items". I seen this done in their other template projects. I am wondering is there the standard way of making your interface?

At first I thought maybe just drop some image buttons on the screen and hook up their click events but now I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XAML Resource essentially does create an instance for you and makes it available in the Resources collection, so you could instantiate the class yourself.  Having it as a resource keeps this object around and makes it accessible across the various pages in your application.  You could certainly create the class explicitly, and if you enforce the singleton pattern on it, it would be semantically equivalent.

I'm not sure I see the context of your second question in the tutorial, but in general the pattern you are seeing is [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj721615), which is the de facto standard pattern for Windows Store apps.  `feedDataSource` is providing the model and portions of that are assigned to `DefaultViewModel`, which is the `DataContext` for all of the binding markup in the XAML pages, which are the views.  The idea behind this to separate your data from your model, so that when you do things like load a new data feed, etc., all you need to do is change the data source, and all of the data binding markup will automatically reflect the new data in your user interface.

If you find yourself writing code that looks like TextBox.Text = "My text", then you're deviating from the pattern.

Comment: Ya it's going to be a while till I get to the MVVM pattern as I need to get a good grip on XAML first. My second question as more when designing the UI I always thought they where using buttons but now after looking at the tutorial and the sample templates I see they are using some sort of gridview item. I was wondering if that is the way people do it in windows 8. I am also wondering if this is the way they do it how do people get images into those gridview items.

Comment: to a large degree XAML and MVVM are joined at the hip :)  As for grid view items (and many other items) in XAML, they are containers and can contain multiple other UI elements, like stackpanels, textblocks, buttons, etc.  For controls that displays lists, like a grid view, you'll typically see a template that includes XAML items like Image, Button, etc., and every element in the ViewModel bound to the collection is rendered according to that template.  So the Image is likely part of a template, and typically references the path to the image as it's Source property.